# Валидация при помощи any

Tags: python

```
   @classmethod
    def _get_header(cls):
        _non_validate = ['{\n', '},\n', '}\n}']
        _headers = []
        with FileManager(cls.file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                if not any(_non_validate) in line:
                    _headers.append(line.split(':')[0].strip('\t"'))
        return _headers
```

Есть функция. Хочу, чтобы она проверяла нет ли в строке хотя бы одного из значений _non_validate, если нет - то аппендила в список. Как синтаксически правильно перенести это в код, мой не работает.

```
   File "/home/artsiom/Desktop/python/JsonPythonConverter/JsonToCsv (1).py", line 115, in _get_header
    if not any(_non_validate) in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

Вот сообщение об ошибке

Comment: `if not any(forbidden in line for forbidden in _non_validate)`.

Comment: Работает, оформите как ответ

Comment: Можете сами. Мне лень :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not any(forbidden in line for forbidden in _non_validate)
```

Comment: `not any(forbidden in line ... )` можно заменить на `all(forbidden not in line ...)`